# Tensorflow : How tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to understand the output of `tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper`
which is [defined here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py) .

I have created a simple program to understand the output of `TrainingHelper` and  `GreedyEmbeddingHelper`  function , my program :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq import TrainingHelper

tf.reset_default_graph()

#inputs

input_data = np.random.randint(0,10,[2,5])
sentence_length = [len(i) for i in input_data]
input_place = tf.placeholder(name='inpu',dtype=tf.int32,shape=[2,5])  #batch_major input
sequence_length_s= tf.placeholder(name='seq_len',dtype=tf.int32,shape=[None])
custom_embedding = tf.get_variable(name='embedding',shape=[10,50],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

embedd_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(custom_embedding,input_place)




helper_fun = TrainingHelper(inputs=input_place,sequence_length=sequence_length_s,time_major=False)

operation = tf.add(input_place,input_place)

ok=helper_fun.initialize(name=None)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  result,b=sess.run([operation,ok],feed_dict={input_place:input_data,sequence_length_s:sentence_length})
  print(b,embedd_input.shape)
```

when i am printing result i am getting random result each time:

first time:

```
(array([False, False]), array([7, 4], dtype=int32)) (2, 5, 50)
```

next_time run :

```
(array([False, False]), array([7, 6], dtype=int32)) (2, 5, 50)
```

Next time :

```
(array([False, False]), array([3, 1], dtype=int32)) (2, 5, 50)
```

I am not getting what actually happening there , And what is [False,False] and what is arry([3,1]) which is changing each time ?

Source code for this class is:

```
def _unstack_ta(inp):
  return tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
      dtype=inp.dtype, size=array_ops.shape(inp)[0],
      element_shape=inp.get_shape()[1:]).unstack(inp)



class TrainingHelper():
  """A helper for use during training.  Only reads inputs.
  Returned sample_ids are the argmax of the RNN output logits.
  """

  def __init__(self, inputs, sequence_length, time_major=False, name=None):
    """Initializer.
    Args:
      inputs: A (structure of) input tensors.
      sequence_length: An int32 vector tensor.
      time_major: Python bool.  Whether the tensors in `inputs` are time major.
        If `False` (default), they are assumed to be batch major.
      name: Name scope for any created operations.
    Raises:
      ValueError: if `sequence_length` is not a 1D tensor.
    """
    with ops.name_scope(name, "TrainingHelper", [inputs, sequence_length]):



      inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs, name="inputs")
      self._inputs = inputs
      if not time_major:
        inputs = nest.map_structure(_transpose_batch_time, inputs)



      self._input_tas = nest.map_structure(_unstack_ta, inputs)


      self._sequence_length = ops.convert_to_tensor(
          sequence_length, name="sequence_length")


      if self._sequence_length.get_shape().ndims != 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Expected sequence_length to be a vector, but received shape: %s" %
            self._sequence_length.get_shape())

      self._zero_inputs = nest.map_structure(
          lambda inp: array_ops.zeros_like(inp[0, :]), inputs)

      self._batch_size = array_ops.size(sequence_length)

  @property
  def inputs(self):
    return self._inputs

  @property
  def sequence_length(self):
    return self._sequence_length

  @property
  def batch_size(self):
    return self._batch_size

  @property
  def sample_ids_shape(self):
    return tensor_shape.TensorShape([])

  @property
  def sample_ids_dtype(self):
    return dtypes.int32

  def initialize(self, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "TrainingHelperInitialize"):
      finished = math_ops.equal(0, self._sequence_length)
      print("dd",finished)
      all_finished = math_ops.reduce_all(finished)
      next_inputs = control_flow_ops.cond(
          all_finished, lambda: self._zero_inputs,
          lambda: nest.map_structure(lambda inp: inp.read(0), self._input_tas))
      return (finished, next_inputs)
```